# Apache 403

Tags: apache

Добрый день.

Не так давно обновился на Fedora 18, столкнулся с проблемой Apache2.

Для сохранности разрабатываемых сайтов, под виртуальные хосты выделен отдельный раздел диска. Диск монтируется в `/srv`

При наличии всех прав и настроенном `selinux`(пробовал отключать) выдет `403 Forbidden`.Вне монтированного раздела диска всё работает

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"Listen 80Include conf.modules.d/*.confUser apacheGroup apacheServerAdmin gedweb@blog.dev<Directory />    AllowOverride All    Require all denied</Directory>DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"<Directory "/var/www">    AllowOverride None    Require all granted</Directory><Directory "/var/www/html">    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride All    Require all granted</Directory><IfModule dir_module>    DirectoryIndex index.html</IfModule><Files ".ht*">    Require all denied</Files>ErrorLog "logs/error_log"LogLevel warn<IfModule log_config_module>    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common    <IfModule logio_module>      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio    </IfModule>    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined</IfModule><IfModule alias_module>    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"</IfModule><Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">    AllowOverride None    Options None    Require all granted</Directory><IfModule mime_module>    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types    AddType application/x-compress .Z    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz    AddType text/html .shtml    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml</IfModule>AddDefaultCharset UTF-8MIMEMagicFile conf/magicEnableSendfile onNameVirtualHost *:80IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

conf.d/vhost.conf

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>        ServerName blog.dev        ServerAlias www.blog.dev        DocumentRoot /srv/www/blog    </VirtualHost>
```

Вот лог ошибки:

```
[Mon Jan 21 17:51:31.080295 2013] [core:crit] [pid 2873] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:36802] AH00529: /srv/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/srv/www/' is executable
```

Comment: Конфиг же в студию. без лишних строк.

Comment: урезал как мог =)

Comment: Диск монтируется в /srvНе вижу в конфиге пути начинающегося с /srv.

Comment: поправил, просто пробовал переносить в домашнюю директорию с использованием `userdir` - результат прежний

Comment: С правами точно все гуд, владелец кто? Нет ли в /srv/www/blog никаких htaccess, и что при 403 в логах апача?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo a2enmod rewritesudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

попробуй, хуже думаю не будет. Это включение модуля rewrite в appache2

Вот [здесь](http://forum.vingrad.ru/act-Print/client/html/f-121/t-173268.html) доступно пишут. По похожей проблеме.